# Vue yells that object is not defined meanwhile it is in scope that requires it being loaded

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

I'd want to do something like:

- foreach line in []
- - parse(line)
- - - return div filled with ids, classnames, etc...
- - display that return

But for some reason I'm receiving error

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.json[index] is undefined"

How's that even possible if bool dataIsLoaded should ensure that it's loaded?

---

```
<div id="app" v-if="dataIsLoaded">
    <div v-for="(obj, index) in json.data">
        {{ parse(index) }}
    </div>
</div>

el: '#app',
data: {
    json: null,
    dataIsLoaded: false
},
beforeCreate: function () {
    fetch("api")
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(json => {
          this.json = json;
          this.dataIsLoaded = true;
      });
},
methods:
{
    parse: function(index)
    {
        var type = this.json[index].name;
        var body = this.json[index].age;

        (...)

        return ...
    }
}
```

**Meanwhile something like this works properly**

```
<div id="app" v-if="dataIsLoaded">
    <div v-for="(obj, index) in json.data">
        {{ index }}{{ obj }}
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Additionally:

```
parse: function(index)
{
    console.log(index);
    var type = this.json[index].name;
    var body = this.json[index].age;

    (...)

    return ...
}
```

console.log(index) returns e.g 0, so index has proper value.

Comment: Should it be `this.json.data[index]` instead? What exactly is `this.json`? Btw: You should not name it `json` as it is an object, not JSON.

Comment: That has to be it; the `json.data` keys don't exist in `json`

Comment: @str I'm an idiot, thanks. Please write it as an answer, so Imma accept.